# CSS Animation With jQuery Not Firing on Second Button Click

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I have a simple table row that is to be highlighted via a jQuery `onClick()` on a button.

When the button is clicked, I remove the animation class (in case it's already there), and then add it back:

```
$("#animate").click(function () {
  $('tr').removeClass('backgroundAnimated');
  $('tr').addClass('backgroundAnimated');
});
```

When the page is first loaded, the first button press works as expected. Pressing a second time, however, doesn't re-start the animation.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojrr3fp6/).

Probably a simple one ;-). Thanks.

Fiona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to other solutions, this method forces the `class` to be added again on every`click` event with less code.

```
$("#animate").on("click", function() {    
      $("tr").removeClass('backgroundAnimated').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(0).addClass('backgroundAnimated');
});
```

**[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ojrr3fp6/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do this code.... Check to see if the `tr` has a class of `backgroundAnimated`. If the element does then remove the class. Else add the the class.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ojrr3fp6/1/)

```
$("#animate").click(function () {
    if(!$('tr').hasClass('backgroundAnimated')){
        $('tr').addClass('backgroundAnimated');
    }else{
       $('tr').removeClass('backgroundAnimated');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
https://jsfiddle.net/8u17gxcp/

```
$("#animate").click(function () {
    var trTemp = $('tbody > tr').clone().removeClass('backgroundAnimated'); //backup the old element
    $('tbody > tr').remove(); //remove the old element
    $('tbody').append(trTemp); //restore the element
    $('tbody > tr').addClass('backgroundAnimated'); //add class to fresh element
});
```

The problem seems to be that re-assigning the class does not trigger the animation's play event, you need to recreate the object.